# Anyone know of an on-line free database?

Tags: c#, database

I wrote an application that currently runs against a local instance of MySql.  I would like to centralize the DB somewhere on the Net, and share my application.

But, I'm cheap, and don't want to pay for it.  Does anyone know of a free on-line relational DB service that I could connect to via C#?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What about http://www.freesql.org ?  Seems like you can't be too picky when you're asking for free, and this seems to offer something.

Comment: The link is wrong (should be `www.freesql.org` instead of `freesql.org`)

Comment: @Yann: that was strange.  I guess two years of link rot can do that. I fixed the link in the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Oops, didn't read the question properly that time! :P

Haven't tried this yet, and their site says they had had a major crash recently, but it looks promising: http://www.freesql.org/

Answer (score 1):

I've never heard of such a thing. A few years ago, many hosts (Brinkster, etc) offered some minimal database capacity with their free web hosting accounts, but I think you'd find it difficult to find something like that now. Even if you could, most hosts no longer allow you to connect to a database (even on an account you're paying for) outside of a web application running on their server.

My advice would be to cobble together an old computer and use that as a database server that you run out of your house (coupled with no-ip or some similar service, probably). If you're going to need more horsepower/bandwidth than that, you'll probably just have to suck it up and pay for something.

Answer (score 1):

Have you taken a look at http://creator.zoho.com/?
I haven't tested it myself but it might be a good idea to check it out.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need [Amazon SimpleDB](http://www.amazon.com/SimpleDB-AWS-Service-Pricing/b?ie=UTF8&node=342335011)...

It's not free, but pricing looks pretty good. I've not used it myself, but when I've got a bit of spare time I might use it for a project I'm working on.

Answer (score 0):

Well, there is http://zymic.com/. They provide free hosting, which includes free databases. Not sure if you can connect to it from outside. You'll have to check that out.